# Google + sign in redirect uri is not call

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to setup a google + sign in on my website

The fact, is that after clicking sign in google + button, and accepted conditions on the consent screen, the redirect uri is not call

this is things I did :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);


 })();

  function render() {
    gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
      //'callback': 'signinCallback',
      'clientid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
      'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    });
  }
  </script>


<div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
                    <a href="" class="btn-social btn-lg btn-ggp"><i class="icon-lg-ggp"></i> Se connecter avec Google+</a>
                </div>
```

[image: API enabled]

[image: Credentials]

I checked the Apache access log in order to check that there is no call from Google server

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Google+ Sign-In button, you do not need to specify a redirect URL and should keep this empty in the console. The button handles the HTTP redirect after auth and issues a JavaScript callback when it receives it.

You have this callback commented out in your code. This should specify the name of a function to call after auth which will receive the code or an indication of failure. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript#step_5_handling_the_sign-in for further details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is that mean that I only handle account connection/disconnection with Ajax call ?